# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND alerts.sinfini.com

Tags: node.js

i'm trying to call the url for sending SMS, getting this kind of error

```
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND alerts.sinfini.com]
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'alerts.sinfini.com' }
```

my node js code is

```
var request = require('request');
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
  }else{
      console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Probably it is error with your local DNS, because address is resolving to 52.74.164.219

Answer (score 0):

In the above code where is the URL defined? Have you checked the URL working fine via rest clients! ENoT thrown for either URL or DNS is not get resolved

Comment: You should give full URL buddy? R u doing that?

Comment: checked both , that url is working fine and getting reply when i type even in the browser